# Way to keep device up with no cable attached? CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I can't seem to find a way to do this in CentOS 7 with Network Manager enabled.

I have SW that requires the front Ethernet connection (enp2s0) be up in order to properly start and work. It will patiently wait forever until the device shows it's state as UP. I have a static IP address on the interface, but there is not always a cable present as the machine might be mobile. Is there a way to keep the device as UP with the static IP address even if a cable is not present? I need to keep NetworkManager enabled for this interface for some scripting purposes.

I  can't seem to find a way to keep it up (can be with NO-CARRIER, but the state needs to be UP).
Running CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core).